# 553 Can't open that file: Permission denied

Tags: git, netbeans, centos7

so, I work with a IDE (NetBeans) and when I try to upload file on the server, I've got this error :

```
Failed:
file      web/config.php     553 Can't open that file: Permission denied
Runtime: 5 ms, processed: 0 file(s), 0 KB
```

But I can download the same file...

Os : CentOs7

A idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: The file probably has read access but not write for your ftp user or group.

Comment: Can you give the permission of this, use **ls -l**.

Comment: Ok that's work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had the same problem -> chown group:user file/folder

Comment: can you add more details to it?